# When I update an existing Windows store app does it add to the previous size of the app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-update

I want to know what exactly happens when I update an app in windows store.Does the update replace the entire old version of the app with the new one or does it add to the previous size.(Eg: suppose i have an app of size 30MB and i get a notification about an update of size 10MB.so if i update will it download 10MB or will it be replaced entirely by the new version of 30MB or more).A proper logical explanation about how this update thing works will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a package for your project, you can see this screenshot:
[image]

If you choose **generate app bundle always**, customers can download faster with an app bundle, because they only download the assets that they need. If you don't generate one, your app will run just fine, but your customers will have to download a larger app.

Based on your description, when you downloaded your app firstly, you may need to download 30 MB, and when you update your app, you just download 10MB.

What’s more, here’s the more detailed information about [**packaging app**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036).

Comment: No, I am not talking about the packing of app. I need to know weather, if i update the app from windows store (windows 10) it follows delta update or some other mechanism?

Comment: Yes, as I said above, if the developer generated app bundle always when he packaged, you just download something(like you said 10MB) that you need to update. If the developer didn't do these, you may need to download a large app(like you said 30MB) to update.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way to verify this upgrade process by means of any log or other thing?

Answer (score 0):

It will be added to the old size. Your app will consume 30+30 = 60

Comment: sry,I have edited the question. It is not about memory consumed by app. it is about how much we download from internet.